# access denied (java.io.FilePermission \images\849cfc1ab7e594e7dba28cfdf37cf9bea87c5de2-privatekey.p12 } in google app engine using drive api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Fed up with this err
access denied (java.io.FilePermission \images\849cfc1ab7e594e7dba28cfdf37cf9bea87c5de2-privatekey.p12 } in google app engine using drive api

I am trying to access drive api using service account.I write the code from 
https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts.

However i am always getting this err while accessing the file @ FIle Reading time at last line.
Here is the code

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
          JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
          GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
              .setTransport(httpTransport)
              .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
              .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
              .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
              .build();
          Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
              .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

Kindly suggest....

Comment: What's the value of `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH`? Looks like your code is trying to access a path outside of what your web app.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine apps can now identify themselves directly, you don't even need to use service accounts. If you don't have a particular reason to use the service, I recommend you to take a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/overview#Asserting_Identity_to_Google_APIs

Answer (score 0):

try to check the properties of your p12 key, it could be lock for security reason do to browser downloading.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `"SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH"` ?

It is very weird to see back slashes in the error :

```
\images\849cfc1ab7e594e7dba28cfdf37cf9bea87c5de2-privatekey.p12
```

One would at least except **forward slashes** for a path relative to the root of your webapp and preferably into the WEB-INF directory for security.Pointing to a directory called '`images`' does not feel reassuring either.